# Can we create an .exe file that uses Python calls without having Python installed in the target machine?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I have this C code i took from https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy as np \n"
"student = np.dtype([('name','S20'), ('age', 'i1'), ('marks', 'f4')])\n" 
"print(student)\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs quite nicely in a machine that has python3 and python3-numpy installed.
The output:

```
[('name', 'S20'), ('age', 'i1'), ('marks', '<f4')]
```

However, if the target machine does not have numpy installed, the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

My question: is it possible to run the python code from the app executable in a target machine that has **no Python3 nor numpy** installed? If so, how do i do it?

I mostly thinking of Win10 as a target machine, but i guess my question would equally apply to other OSes.

Thanks!

EDIT: To be more exact, I am not asking if this code can be compiled without having Python installed. I know it must have some python-dev to be compiled.

But what I want to know is there a way to create an .exe file that uses some Python calls **without having Python installed in the target machine**?

Comment: Where do you expect your program to get all its Python functionality from without Python?

Comment: This code clearly calls Python and the Python numpy library, so no, it cannot be done. But I imagine it should be possible to install them on a Win10 box too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). It will wrap your Python code, a Python interpreter, and the packages you need into a standalone .exe file.

Specifically, numpy is on the [list of supported packages](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages).

I would get rid of the C program, put your main Python code in a .py file, and let PyInstaller do the work for you.

This is a much better solution than requiring your users to have a Python interpreter installed, much less any particular libraries and packages. It allows each application to have its own version of Python and packages.

Full details are in the [PyInstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Thanks! However, i cannot get rid of the C program, since the main work is done by the C part. The python will only create a few animation files in new launched processes.

Comment: Ah yes, that changes things. Here's another idea: Do your C and Python code need to share data in memory? Or would it work to run the Python code in a separate process launched from the C code, and share data using files or stdin/stdout or named pipes or...? If a separate Python process works, then you could use PyInstaller to build that executable.

Comment: One more idea while we're brainstorming: You could invert this and make Python be your main program, compile your C code into a DLL, and use either the native Python/C API or something like Clif or Swig to make it easier to call if you use C++. Either way you could still use PyInstaller to bundle your binaries together.